# Replace integer in the middle of string multiple times (Bash Sed?)

Tags: bash, sed, replace

Still working on my sed usage, but here's the very simple run down:

I would like to replace an integer within a string and do so x number of times. A user will input a string with "&Page=#&PageSize=#" such as the one below and from there the integer must be changed and on each change it must be appended to a file.

```
20601300929&Page=1&PageSize=96
```

What needs to be replaced is very simply "Page=1" to "Page=2". I could build a counter that increases the integer, but what I need is to automate the process of identifying and replacing the integer and then appending each counted change into a text file.

The expected result would be a simple file containing:

```
20601300929&Page=1&PageSize=96
20601300929&Page=2&PageSize=96
20601300929&Page=3&PageSize=96
... Until 100
```

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`? The problem is `sed` cannot count; `bash` and `awk` can.

Comment: Ah thank you, of course yes it can be more, I was simply in the brain space of sed for the text replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with awk:

```
echo '20601300929&Page=1&PageSize=96' |
awk -F "Page=" '
    {
        split($2,a,"&")
        for (i=int(a[1]);i<=100;i++){
            print $1 FS a[1]++ "&" a[2]
        }
    }'
```

The field separator is set to `Page=`, so that field `$2` is `1&PageSize=96` in our example.

The `split` bit splits that second field based on `&` and put in `a[1]` the number and in `a[2]` the rest of the string (`PageSize=96`).

Finally, in the print statement all is glued together.

Comment: Wow that worked like a treat! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Question: While implementing in a script I have the original string pasted after the full executable, making it $1. So I've replaced "echo 'string' |" with "echo '$1' |" and it stopped working altogether. After using no single quotes around $1, I found that it forgot to add the end bit (&PageSize=96) back to the string.... What am I missing? Thx

Comment: @Tmanok You're welcome, glad to help. You should double quote: `"$1"`. When running the script, you should also double-quote the argument: `./script "20601300929&Page=1&PageSize=96"`.

Comment: Ah excellent thank you! Yes bash was getting rather confused when insert the strings because of how it handles ampersand and other characters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe bash

```bsh
num=96
counter=1
limit=100
var='20601300929&Page=#&PageSize=#'

while ((counter<=limit)); do
  if [[ $var =~ ([^\&]+)(\&[^\&]+)(.+) ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]/\#/$((counter++))}${BASH_REMATCH[3]/\#/$num}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: This one worked very well when using the "#" where the variables are, thank you very much I love the pure bash!